# How to set USB serial as debug port / console?

Tags: usb, embedded-linux

I'm working on an iMX23 cpu with linux-2.6.35.3 and wondering if this is even possible to implement.
I can build g_serial and g_multi and use the serial port function, which uses /dev/ttyGS0.
Do I just have to change [console=ttyS0] to [console=ttyGS0] on the kernel command line?

Thanks

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63104542/can-usb-otg-be-used-for-u-boot-and-linux-consoles

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems you can easily add another console port just by adding another setting in [/etc/inittab]

```
::respawn:/sbin/getty -L ttyAM0 115200 vt100
::respawn:/sbin/getty -L ttyGS0 115200 vt100
```

Adding another line as above will enable you to use USB serial as console too(/dev/ttyGS0).

Comment: That is for setting up additional terminals, not consoles.  Text from **printk()** (of adequate loglevel) will be displayed on the console(s), but not all/any terminals.

Comment: @sawdust, I guess I have just mixed up my terminologies. another "terminal" was what I needed.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it should be that simple.  Just change your kernel command line to "console=ttyGS0,115200" or similar.  You'll find it even works with usb ports ie "console=ttyUSB0" for example.